# Unable to find component with id 'FooPopup'

Tags: wicket, wicket-7

I found this strange error in the production logs:

```
Unable to find component with id 'FooPopup' in [Form [Component id = FooForm]]
    Expected: 'FooPanel:FooForm:FooPopup'.
    Found with similar names: 'FooPanel:FooForm:FooPopup'>.
```

I cannot reproduce this locally.
Do you know what could be the reason for this since the expected and the found item have exactly the same name?
Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Can you show the java code and markup, please.

Answer (score 0):

Such kind of errors occur when a Wicket component is made invisible after interaction with it.

For example if a user clicks twice on an Ajax link/button and the first click makes the component invisible then the second one will fail with this error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The specific link is not made invisible when clicked though and I still can not reproduce the issue.