# Unable to find component with id 'text'

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

From time to time i find this error in production logs - "Unable to find component with id 'text'". I cannot reproduce it. What the reason of this error and how to fix it?

In code i have panel toolBarPanel which contains other panel with id = "exit" which contains label with id = "text".

I found similar question but it doesn't  resolve my issue
[Unable to find component with id 'FooPopup'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58929934/unable-to-find-component-with-id-foopopup)

**ToolBarPanel.java**

```java
    public ToolBarPanel(String id, String pageName, String userName, List<ToolbarMenuItem> menuItems, final Class<?> thisPage) {
        super(id);
        setOutputMarkupId(true);
        
        // some piece of code here ...
        
        // 1st exit is ID, AlfaAjaxLink extends Panel
        add(new AlfaAjaxLink("exit", "exit") {  
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                dialog.setInitialHeight(130).setInitialWidth(270);
                dialog.show(target);
            }
        });
        
        ListView<ToolbarMenuItem> menu = new ListView<ToolbarMenuItem>("menuItems", menuItems) {
            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem<ToolbarMenuItem> item) {
                final ToolbarMenuItem menuItem = item.getModelObject();
                String cssClassName = menuItem.getPage().equals(thisPage) ? "selected-toolbar-menu-item" : "toolbar-menu-item"; 
                item.add(new AlfaAjaxLink("menuItem", menuItem.getName(), cssClassName, "FFFFFF")  {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                        setResponsePage(getResponsePage(menuItem));
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        add(menu);
    }
```

**AlfaAjaxLink.java (extends Button)**

```java
    public AlfaAjaxLink(String id, String text) {
        this(id, text, null, null);
    }

    public AlfaAjaxLink(String id, String text, String cssClassName, String textColor) {
        super(id);
        init(text, cssClassName, textColor);
    }

    private void init(String text, String cssClassName, String textColor) {
        AjaxLink button = createAjaxLink();
        label = createLabel(text);
        if (textColor != null) {
            label.add(AttributeModifier.replace("style", "color : #" + textColor));
        }
        if (cssClassName != null) {
            button.add(AttributeModifier.replace("class", cssClassName));
        }
        button.add(label);
        add(button);
    }
    
    protected Label createLabel(String text) {
    // here is ID text
        return new Label("text", text);
    }
```

**HomePage.java**

```
public class HomePage extends AAppBasePage {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6944890517661999946L;

    public HomePage() {
        super("Home Page");
        setOutputMarkupId(true);
        if (getUsersDebtorType() != null) {
            throw new RestartResponseException(MyClass.class);
        } else {
            add(new Label("text", "SomeText"));
        } 
    }
}
```

**HomePage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.sourceforge.net/">
<wicket:extend>
    <div class="rsftextlabel"><div wicket:id="text"></div></div>
</wicket:extend>
</html>
```

**ToolBarPanel.html**

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.sourceforge.net/">
<wicket:panel>
    <div wicket:id="logoutDialog"></div>
    <div style="width : 100%">
            <TABLE cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="2px" width="100%" border="0">
                <TBODY>
                    <TR>
                        <td><img width="48px" height="48px" wicket:id="logo"></img></td>
                        <TD align="left" width="100%">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size: 18px;">My application</td>
                                    <td style="font-size: 18px;">&nbsp;&nbsp; / &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td style="font-size: 18px;"><div wicket:id="pageName"></div></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </TD>
                        <TD vAlign="middle" noWrap>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><table>
                                        <tr><td colspan="2"><div wicket:id="surname"></div></td></tr>
                                        <tr><td><div wicket:id="name"></div></td><td><div wicket:id="patronymic"></div></td></tr>
                                    </table></td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td valign="center"><div wicket:id="exit"></div></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </TR>
                </TBODY>
            </TABLE>
    </div>
    
    <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 1px; background-color: #A3A3A3; widht: 150%; margin-left: -10px; margin-right: -10px; height : 5px;"></div>

    <div style="width : 100%">
            <span wicket:id="menuItems">
                <a wicket:id="menuItem"></a>
            </span>
    </div>

</wicket:panel>
</html>
```

**Button.html**

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.sourceforge.net/">
<wicket:panel>
    <a wicket:id="button" class="alfa-button">
        <span wicket:id="text" class="alfa-button-text"></span>
        <wicket:child/>
    </a>
</wicket:panel>
</html>
```

**LOGS**

```sh
ERROR [org.apache.wicket.DefaultExceptionMapper] (default task-189) Unexpected error occurred: Unable to find component with id 'text' in [TransparentWebMarkupContainer [Component id = _wicket_extend44]]
        Expected: '_wicket_child31:_wicket_extend32:_wicket_child43:_wicket_extend44.text'.
        Found with similar names: 'toolBarPanel:exit', toolBarPanel:exit:button:text', toolBarPanel:menuItems:0:menuItem:button:text', toolBarPanel:menuItems:1:menuItem:button:text', toolBarPanel:menuItems:2:menuItem:button:text', toolBarPanel:menuItems:3:menuItem:button:text', toolBarPanel:menuItems:4:menuItem:button:text', toolBarPanel:menuItems:5:menuItem:button:text', toolBarPanel:menuItems:6:menuItem:button:text', toolBarPanel:menuItems:7:menuItem:button:text', toolBarPanel:menuItems:8:menuItem:button:text'
     MarkupStream: [markup = file:/JBOSS/AppServer_FSSP_J7/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/temp8f5ee2f7c4f4e6b2/content-e7709a14d279cc75/ru/cinimex/alfa/fssp/ui/wicket/pages/HomePage.html
    <wicket:extend>
        <div class="rsftextlabel"><div wicket:id="text"></div></div>
    </wicket:extend>, index = 2, current =  '<div wicket:id="text">' (line 0, column 0)]
        at org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupStream.throwMarkupException(MarkupStream.java:526) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1473) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1592) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1567) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1521) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:72) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2563) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1530) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2393) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2321) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1428) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1592) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1567) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1521) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:72) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2563) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1530) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2393) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2321) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1428) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1592) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1567) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1521) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:72) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2563) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1530) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2393) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2321) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1428) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1592) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1567) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1521) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:72) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2563) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1530) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2393) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2321) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1428) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1592) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.Page.onRender(Page.java:907) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage.onRender(WebPage.java:140) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2393) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2321) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:1035) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:118) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:198) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:167) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:784) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64) [wicket-request-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:255) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:212) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:283) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:188) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:244) [wicket-core-1.5.10.jar:1.5.10]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:55)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
```

Comment: Hi. I see you are using a TransparentWebMarkupContainer. Could you provide your markup code as well? It might be a problem with auto components (https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_auto_components_resolvers)

Comment: Hi Andrea. I attached markup code. I don't use TransparentWebMarkupContainer explicitly in my code. I use Wicket 1.5. Could you tell me more precisely what the problem with auto compenents it could be.

Answer (score 2):

The AlfaAjaxLink is not the problem.

Search for `<div class="rsftextlabel">` in your markup files. This `<div>` element contains the problematic `<div wicket:id="text"></div>`. It seems you don't add a Java component for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is page "HomePage" and i have Java component for it (attached java and html to the topic). I think it's ok.

Comment: It is OK! But you use Wicket 1.5.x and I remember an issue where Wicket was trying to render the page even after scheduling a new one via `RestartResponseException`. Either update Wicket to a newer version or add a dummy component before throwing the exception, e.g. `add(new EmptyPanel("text"))`

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately 1.5 is quite old and it misses many improvements and bug fixes done for use cases like this. I think that the problem you are facing has been solved with this patch:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-5580